# Filepicker.io Widget - Other Mimetime

Tags: filepicker.io

How do I go about entering ".ZIP" and ".RAR" as the allowed mimetypes for the filepicker.io widget?

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the data-fp-extensions attribute, for instance

```
<input type="filepicker" data-fp-extensions="zip,rar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of allowed mimetype. add 'application/zip' to the list and you are good to go

```
var allowedMimeTypeList =['image/*', 'text/plain', 'application/pdf','application/msword','application/vnd.ms-powerpoint','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation','application/zip'];

filepicker.pick({
          mimetypes: allowedMimeTypeList,
          //container : 'window'
          },
});
```